# SQL statement to get a total for a given date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get the number of bookings and their total value by date for every day within a given date range.

### My table looks like:

```
BookingId (int)
BookingFare (decimal)
BookingDateTime (datetime)
```

I can convert BookingDateTime to a date only by using:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(8), BookingDateTime, 112) as BookingDateOnly
FROM   [TaxiBookingOnline].[dbo].[Bookings]
```

What I'm after is something like this:

```
Date         Bookings   Value
2013-07-10   10         256.24
2013-07-11   12         321.44
2013-07-12   14         311.53
```

I get the feeling I should be aliasing the table, joining it to itself and then using 'GROUP BY' but I am failing to get this to work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
select
   cast(BookingDateTime as date) [Date],
   count(*) [Bookings],
   sum(BookingFare) [Value]
from t
group by cast(BookingDateTime as date)
```

Comment: Unbelievable! You make this seem so easy! I really must spend some timing getting my head around SQL. Thanks very much indeed!

Comment: @user975516 Note that this is only valid on SQL Server 2008 and later. Earlier versions do not support the Date type.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT   CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), BookingsDateTime, 112) AS [Date],
         COUNT(*)  AS [Bookings],
         SUM(BookingsFare AS [Value]
FROM     MyTable
GROUP BY DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, BookingDateTime))
```

Group by `SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, dateColumn))` which will effectively get the date portion of the `datetime`, then you can use `count` or `sum` as necessary on the grouped values.

EDIT: If you're using SQL Server >= 2008, you can cast to [`date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx) (like @AlexK has done) otherwise you have to hack around it using `DATEADD`.

Comment: Many thanks. DATEADD is useful to know. I'm on 2012 so was able to cast to date.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the code. Replace Date1 and Date2 with the date range values:

```
SELECT 
CONVERT(varchar(8), BookingDateTime, 112) as BookingDateOnly, BookingID   Bookings,Sum(BookingFare)Value  
FROM 
[TaxiBookingOnline].[dbo].[Bookings]
WHERE BookingDateTime Between 'Date1' and 'Date2'
GROUP BY
BookingDateTime,BookingID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(DATE,BookingDateTime) BookingDate,
    COUNT(BookingID) Bookings,
    SUM(BookingFare) BookingFare
FROM TaxiBookingOnline.dbo.Bookings
```